# Phase 10 Going Out - Do you keep picking up?

Tags: phase-10

I've just picked up a copy of Phase 10 to play with my kids. I'm a little confused about the 'Going Out' part. Once you get a phase and place it on the table, you can place any appropriate cards on your own and your opponents' phases, or the discard pile. The object is to get rid of your hand. Do you still just carry on picking cards up and discarding them until you happen to be able to get rid of them all (or your opponent does)? Or do you just discard one at a time?

EDIT: I think I've just realised that you can 'Hit' a phase at any point, so you could pick up a card, Hit it on to a phase, *and* discard a card into the discard pile. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before making your phase, your turn structure is like this:

1. You MUST draw a card from the deck or discard pile.
2. You MAY make your phase and put it on the table.
3. You MUST discard a card onto the discard pile.

When making your phase you MAY immediately add any number of your own cards to other phases on the table. Afterwards, you MUST discard a card to end your turn.

Then after making your phase, your turn structure is like this:

1. You MUST draw a card from the deck or discard pile.
2. You MAY add any number of cards from your hand to the phases on the table.
3. You MUST discard a card onto the discard pile.

The round ends immediately when a player gets rid of their last card.